# How to set output encoding of simplexml_load_string PHP function

Tags: php, encoding, simplexml, output

I am parsing CP1250 encoded string with `simplexml_load_string`. So, I state it at string beginning by `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>`. Unfortunately, all nodes are UTF8 encoded in `simplexml_load_string` output.

Is there a way, how to specify output encoding as well or do I have to use iconv whenever using the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear to me so I try to answer it in the ways I understand it, likely the answer is given then.

If you load a CP1250/Windows-1250 encoded string and that string contains this encoding information in the XML declration, normally by default simplexml already keeps this for the output. So normally you don't need to do anything here.

If you however need to set the output encoding explicitly:

A `SimpleXMLElement` does not allow you to change the encoding by it's own. However like often when SimpleXML can't do it on it's own, the sister library `DOMDocument` is able to. Because both are sisters, they can interact on each other. In the following example I load an UTF-8 encoded string and then set the xml output encoding to US-ASCII explicitly:

```
$inputUTF8 = <<<INPUT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    Äpfel wachsen überirdisch
</root>
INPUT;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($inputUTF8); // load UTF-8 encoded string
$xml->asXML('php://output'); // outputs as UTF-8 (same as input by default)

// set document encoding to US-ASCII via DOMDocument
$doc = dom_import_simplexml($xml)->ownerDocument;
$doc->encoding = 'US-ASCII';

$xml->asXML('php://output'); // outputs as US-ASCII
```

The output is as followed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    Äpfel wachsen überirdisch
</root>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<root>
    &#196;pfel wachsen &#252;berirdisch
</root>
```

As this shows, the `DOMDocument::$encoding` property changes the output encoding even of teh `SimpleXMLElement`, also characters that are not part of the character set are expressed as their numeric XML entity for their Unicode-codepoint (here `Ä` is U+00C4 which is hexedecimal for decimal 196. Using *Windows-1250* as output encoding would give me an unkown character error on the screen:

```
// set document encoding to Windows-1250 via DOMDocument
$doc = dom_import_simplexml($xml)->ownerDocument;
$doc->encoding = 'Windows-1250';

$xml->asXML('php://output'); // outputs as Windows-1250
```

Ouput (UTF-8 display):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1250"?>
<root>
    �pfel wachsen �berirdisch
</root>
```

The binary octets `C4` and `FC` can not be displayed as UTF-8 so here in my case `�` are shown. This also shows that the output *is* in Windows-1250 encoding, otherwise the display would show these characters as they are.

I hope this is helpful even - as written in the beginning of my answer - from what you describe it is not necessary to specify the output encoding. If things are running differently on your end than outlined in this answer please share your PHP and libxml version.